# Jena tdbloader and tdbloader2 memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, jena

I was trying to use tdbloader2 to load Freebase dump. But I got an exception: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap "

I increase the JVM_ARGS to -Xmx60G, and still get the same exception. （My machine has 64G).

I switched to tdbloader, and use top to monitor the memery consumption, and the memory usage increase dramatically to 15G in less than half an hour.

======

More info:

The dump is rdf format, and I splitted it into multiple ttl files, each is about 700M, and totally 90G.

I used

```
tdbloader2 --loc kg x*.ttl
```

And I modified the tdbloader2 script, changed the line

```
JVM_ARGS=${JVM_ARGS:--Xmx1024M}
```

to be

```
JVM_ARGS=${JVM_ARGS:--Xmx60G}
```

I don't have the exact error output now. But I remember it failed when it tried to create a new HashMap.

Comment: What format is the Freebase dump?  Unless it is in N-Triples format, tdbloader might have to load the whole model into memory before writing the indices, etc., to disk.  If the dump is too large, that would obviously require lots of memory.  Can you add to your question:  the command line that you use to invoke `tdbloader2`, as well as the size and format of your data file?

Comment: Should be OK for that point of view, tdbloader (1 and 2) does not read the whole file in first.

Comment: At what point in the load does it fail?

tdbloader2 is a script - make sire JVM_ARGS is properly exported to the environment else it will have no effect.

Comment: @AndyS Oh, I didn't think that RDF/XML and N3 could be easily split without having read the whole document and constructed a model from it.  Now that I think of it, that doesn't make sense;  as long as you don't have to read the whole XML document in, there probably wouldn't be a problem.  My mistake.